# How to set Sum distinct in reporting?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, reporting

is there a way to set **group_operator** as **SUM(DISTINCT column)** in reporting :
I have the following view :

```
SELECT   
    sale_id,   
    COUNT( product_id),
    SUM(DISTINCT sale_qty) sale_qty ,
    SUM(delivered_qty) delivered_qty
FROM sale_delivery
WHERE sale_id=3063
GROUP BY sale_id
```

Comment: Just replace `GROUP BY sale_id` with `GROUP BY 1, 3` where `3` sets your third column in your select statement which is `SUM(DISTINCT sale_qty)`.

Comment: @KuKeC ProgrammingError: aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY

Comment: Yes it is possible. What is the error you get?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto how it's possible ?

Comment: Did you try it and got an error or what?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto the view work fine but in odoo reporting use group_operation="sum" return false values